# How to "join"? multiple dataframes to one in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have 100 excel files formatted as dataframes like this with varying names:

| Key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |

And:

| Key | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Z |
| 2 | A |

I have one main file formatted like this:

| Index | Key |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

I'd like to merge the 100 files to the one dataframe in a 'messy' way.
Creating something that looks like this:

| Key | Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | Z |
| 2 | Y | A |

How would I write a loop to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
path = r"C:\Users\.......\testing_read"
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
  

data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
content = []
  

for filename in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", index_col='Key')
    content.append(df)
  

df = pd.concat(content, axis = 1)
```

which returns what you wanted.

```
    Name Name
Key          
1      X    Z
2      Y    A
```

However, this is not a very good idea if you end upp with 100 columns named `Name`.

If I were you I'd do this:

```
path = r"C:\Users\.....\testing_read"
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
  

data_frame = pd.DataFrame()
content = []
  

for filename in files:

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=";", index_col='Key')
    content.append(df)
  

df = pd.concat(content)
```

which returns:

```
Name
Key     
1      X
2      Y
1      Z
2      A
```